# MVVM with multiple projects Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvm, constructor, interface

Hellow , i am a student and i am working on a project. It is a Xamarin native project (cross-platform). I Use MVVM. This was working perfect when i was using 1 shared project and my 3other projects (android,iOS,winphone). Now I have different projects for my shared code.

-Appname.Repositories

-Appname.Services

-Appname.Viewmodel

Now the problem is that when i start my app using an constructor in my viewmodel with an interface he is given me the next error :

//Constructor

```
public LoginViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger, IUserDataService userDataService) : base(messenger)
        {
            _userDataService = userDataService;
        }
```

Error:

MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type C_Tracker.Mobile.Domain.ViewModel.LoginViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check InnerException for more information

InnerException :

MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter userDataService of type IUserDataService

But when i use a constructor without this interface it is working.

```
public LoginViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger) : base(messenger)
        {

        }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you forgot about Dependencies Injection.
Add to Setup.cs something like this `Mvx.RegisterType<IUserDataService, UserDataService>();`
For more information about ServiceLocator please check https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/service-location-and-inversion-of-control